# Angular 4 - displaying message after an asynchronous call

Tags: angular

I have a page where I display a list of posts, and clicking on each of them I am displaying comments for that post. That works fine, what I wanted to add is to display a message if there are no comments for the post that was clicked. I have tried with setting up the template like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)" >
      {{ post.title }}
      <ul *ngIf="currentPost == post && commentsVisible">
        <ng-container *ngIf="currentPost.comments.length > 0;else message">
          <li *ngFor="let comment of currentPost.comments" class="document">
            <p>{{ comment.author }}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #message>No comments for {{ post.title }}</ng-template>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

And in the component, I have tried to first set the empty `posts` array, and an empty `currentPost` object with a property `comments`:

```
  posts: any[] = [];
  currentPost: any = {};
  currentPost.comments;
```

And then in the method `select` I am fetching the comments like this:

```
this.postService.getComments(post.id)
      .subscribe(
        comments => this.currentPost.comments = comments,
      );
```

But, if I do so, I get an error:

> posts.component.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'
>   of undefined

How can I avoid that error, and check and display a message after a async call to the service method `getComments`?

Comment: Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker. I tried and I could not reproduce (with the safe navigation operator suggested by Dani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `currentPost.comments?.length` in order to get rid of that error.

Comment: I have tried that, but then I also have the problem of  getting the #message for each post, even for the ones that have comments

Comment: As a second solution to you ngIfElse - try to use `*ngIf="currentPost.comments?.length == 0"` in order to post "No comments for..."

Comment: I think the problem is that it evaluates before the async call is finished and then it will always be false

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out, the mistake was somewhere else, this works, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for this problem is to use the `async pipe` (more info [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)).
Add the pipe into the *ngFor statement.
Current situation: 
`<li *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="select(post)">`

With async pipe:
`<li *ngFor="let post of posts | async" (click)="select(post)">`